# Alias value in avsc does not display value on par with avro file

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have updated avsc file to rename column like,

```
 "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "department_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "office_name",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null,
    "aliases" : [ "department_name" ],
    "columnName" : "department_name"
  }
```

However in may avro file columns are like `department_id : 10, department_name : "maths"`

Now when i query like below,

```
select office_name from t
```

it always returns `null values`. Will it not return value from department_name in avro. Is there a way to have multiple names for column in avsc

Comment: Can you share `describe t` output

Comment: @wypul describe output is like `office_name string`

Answer (score 0):

From [cloudera community](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Spark-sql-fails-to-use-quot-SELECT-quot-on-Aliases-on/td-p/45962), "we recommend to use the original name rather than the aliased name of the field in the table, as the Avro aliases are stripped during loading into Spark."

**Schema with aliases,**

```
val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("../spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/resources/user.avsc"))
```

schema: org.apache.avro.Schema = {"type":"record","name":"User","namespace":"example.avro","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string","aliases":["customer_name"],"columnName":"customer_name"},{"name":"favorite_color","type":["string","null"],"aliases":["color"],"columnName":"color"}]}

**Spark striping the aliases**,

```
val usersDF = spark.read.format("avro").option("avroSchema",schema.toString).load("../spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/resources/users.avro")
```

usersDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, favorite_color: string]

I guess you can go with spark builtin features to rename a column, but if you find any other workaround let me know as well.

Comment: The original question seems to refer to hive not spark . he is trying aa hive query  select office_name from t  . I am also facing same issue in hive . does hive also ignore alias like spark?